# About self validated Java POJOs

Tags: java, validation, spring

I am currently experimenting with self validating Java beans in order to avoid the creation of objects with invalid states, while keeping the validation knowledge inside the bean. The goals I have in mind are:

1. Avoid polluting the bean with too much validation code for readability purposes.
2. Make the validation process compatible with the use of Lombok or Java records, so that any bean can be validated.
3. Keep compatibility with the use of `@Valid` in Spring `@RestController`s for validating JSON bodies, so that violation errors can be identified and returned in the responses.

After googling and thinking a bit, the best version I have is given below. The logic is based on the use of [Jakarta validations + Hibernate validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints). I am sharing the code to get opinions and feedback about the idea and possible drawbacks or improvements.

**NOTE:** [See full code in Github](https://github.com/silver-mx/self-validated-beans)

##### SelfValidated interface

```
/**
 * This interface allows a bean to exercise all the jakarta validations defined. All beans need to implement this interface,
 * and call validate() in order to be validated.
 */
public interface SelfValidated {

    /* NOTE: ValidatorFactory should be closed when the VM is shutting down (see App.java) */
    static final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    static final Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();


    default void validate() {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<SelfValidated>> violations = validator.validate(this);

        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }
}
```

##### Immutable Java bean + Lombok

```
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", setterPrefix = "with")
@JsonDeserialize(builder = UserPojo.Builder.class)
public class UserPojo implements SelfValidated {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
    String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 30)
    String password;

    private UserPojo(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        validate();
    }
}
```

##### Java Record

```
public record UserRecord(

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
        String username,

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 8, max = 30)
        String password,

        @NotNull
        @Email
        String email) implements SelfValidated {

    public UserRecord(final String username, final String password, final String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        validate();
    }
}
```

#### General feelings

From the original goals, I see:

**Advantages**

- A guarantee that each object will have a valid state.
- The beans encapsulate their validation logic so it is clear what valid values are.
- The use of Hibernate [Jakarta validations + Hibernate validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints) makes the code very readable and it does not feel polluted.
- Throwing `ConstraintViolationException` allows the catcher to identify the violations detected in the bean. This works ok with Spring, but it changes a bit the usual behavior if compared with the use of `@Valid + @RequestBody`. It this case, the exception is different and it will be thrown even if `@Valid` is not given.
- By adding intelligence to the bean we add a reason to create unit test to verify that everything works as expected.

**Disadvantages**

- The approach works for immutable beans. For mutable ones, the method `validate()` needs to be called and that could be easily missed.
- The beans suddenly take more importance and work as they now include actual logic, when traditionally they have been plain boring objects. Unsure if this is an actual disadvantage though.
- Unsure if the use of [Jakarta validations + Hibernate validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints) may have a performance penalty if too many objects are created/validated.
- The `ValidatorFactory` created inside the interface `SelfValidated` remains open during the life of the application in order to allow the `Validator` to do its job. As it is a static field used by all classes, I suppose is should not be a problem. Still it feels not ideal.

Does anyone has any opinion or feedback about this implementation? Any experience with something similar you have tried?

Comment: If the objects are immutable (which they should be), can't they just be validated on construction? Constructors can throw, preventing existence of an invalid object. With a "self-validating interface", the object will exist in memory and can maybe even be used inadvertently, and we have to trust that the consumer calls and heeds the validation method.

Comment: In my examples I do the call to `validate()` in the `build()` of a `Builder` (keeping a private constructor) or in the constructor of a record. As you mention, the object must be completely initialized (all fields set) for `validate()` to work, but a consumer will never get a reference to the newly created object because an exception will be thrown before (either in a constructor or `build()`). Still, `validate()` can be called wherever it is needed. In my `@Builder` example I was experimenting with Lombok, but `validate()` could be called in the constructor as well (a bit more verbose).

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point, when you say "the object will exist in memory and can maybe even be used inadvertently", do you have like an unusual case in mind. Maybe I am blind of my own code but what I see is that a consumer will never get a reference to the actual object even though the object is actually created.

Comment: I moved the call to `validate()` to the constructor in `UserPojo` instead of having in it in the `build()` method. You are right, the constructor is a better place to do such things. Consistency helps in the long run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Content warning: *this may be controversial and go against a lot of established practises.*

I think you have figured out the advantages and disadvantages pretty well except for one thing. Having validation annotations in your data objects makes them unreusable. Using your example, if you need a `UserPojo` for a new user that doesn't have password yet, you need to write a completely new class (or initialize the existing POJO with a magic string, which doesn't sound good at all). You could look up conditional validation libraries, but then you would be creating a spaghetti plate of non standardized rules with low visibility into your code. Accepting this limitation would require you to rename the generic `UserPojo` into something that describes it's specific intended use case.

Data validity is more often dependant on the operation being done. Therefore I prefer having the validation being tied to the operation instead of the data. Annotations, when they are useful, are good for ensuring input lengths and formats. But even those can cause problems. It's the same kind of a balancing act as any other code.

Comment: Good point. Everything is a trade-off. I started experimenting with this just to get a feeling of how beneficial it could be, but as you imply, imposing validations in all objects to create consistency in the codebase could lead to an overly strict/constrained environment which is not good. On the other hand, keeping the validations outside the class (depending on the operation) may lead to inconsistency as some people may use validations while others not. Another disadvantage is that the validation rules and the actual data are kept separate which breaks the domain rules in different parts.